# How to do a POST to another file AND load that file inside the main file?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, mysql

Ok, I have 3 files. 
- index.php 
- verTicket.php (means getTicket.php) 
- VerTickets.php

On index.php, I have a header, a slider and a div holding content.

    `<div id="bigBody"></div>`

On the same index.php, I have a link to verTickets.php. 
`<li><a href="#" onClick="$('#bigBody').load('verTickets.php')" id="getAllTickets">All Tickets</a></li>`

Clicking this links, loads verTickets.php into the bigBody id.
Them, I populate a table with SQL content, including a clickable link:
`ECHO "<td><a class='ticketLink' id='" . $row['id'] . "'>". $row['title'] . "</a></td>";`

Then, the JavaScript:

```
   $(document).ready(
        function() {
            $(".ticketLink").click(function() {
                window.alert(this.id); //Test to see if id is being passed.
                $.post("verTicket.php", {
                operation: "createTicket",
                ticketId: "Test id"
                });        
            });
        }
    );
```

I've tested the `$.post` to insert data on the MySQL server and it worked. But I want to POST without refreshing  and load the page inside my bigBody div.

@EDIT - Solution!
Thanks, @timgavin

Inside my verTicket.php is a table using MySQL_Fetch. Don't know if I did understood your answer, Tim. So, I've tried to create a variable inside my verTicket.php and put everything generated by the sql queries inside it so I can return and use the html.

But, in the process of doing this, I've come into this:
    `$("#bigBody").load("verTicket.php", {ticketId: (this.id), title:     (this.innerHTML)});`
with this code, I could pass my post variables into verTicket.php and, AFTER the processing, load the full page.

Thank you! :)
`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: if the query fails in verTicket.php, return a 'fail' message, or, if it's successful return the data you want to load.

verTicket.php

```
if(database query is successful) {
    return/echo the data here
} else {
    die('fail');
}
```

---

Then, in your `.post` javascript function, check to see if the returned data is 'fail', and if it isn't, load the returned data into the div, otherwise print an error message.

```
$.post('verTicket.php',{operation: "createTicket",ticketId: "Test id"}, function(response) {
    if(response != 'fail') {
        $('#bigBody').html(response);
    } else {
        // error code goes here
    }
});
```